# Linking Qt + CUDA + external library

Tags: qt, opengl, ubuntu, cuda

I've written a PRO file to generate a GUI for my CUDA application under linux (already compiled under windows now porting same components to ubuntu 1404).

I've first compiled a helper library "mylib.a" and linked that with my application "myapp.cu" and tested that it compiles and runs nicely without Qt in the picture (done via nsight eclipse).

For building with Qt I've generated the following PRO file:

```
#############################
# basic PRO file for qmake
##############################


# QT libs to use
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
##########################################
# QT basic files
##########################################
SOURCES+=main.cpp
SOURCES+=myGUI.cpp

HEADERS += myGUI.h
FORMS   += myGUI.ui

# Project dir and outputs
PROJECT_DIR = $$system(pwd)
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PROJECT_DIR/Obj
DESTDIR = ../bin

##########################################
# CUDA source files
##########################################
CUDA_SOURCES += myApp.cu
CUDA_SOURCES += kernel1.cu
CUDA_SOURCES += kernel2.cu

##########################################
# CUDA related components
##########################################

CUDA_DIR = /usr/local/cuda
CUDA_ARCH = sm_35
NVCCFLAGS = --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -use_fast_math --ptxas-options=-v


##########################################
# include paths
##########################################
# CUDA
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include


# Additional dependencies

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/

##########################################
# library directories
##########################################
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib64
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/samples/common/lib


##########################################
#  LIBS
##########################################

LIBS += -lnvToolsExt
LIBS += -lopengl
#libcudart_static
#LIBS += -lcudart_static
LIBS += -lcuda
LIBS += -lcudart
LIBS += -lGL
# My library is added here
LIBS += -lmyLib 

# join the includes in a line
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,' -I','-I',' ')


##########################################
# Extra compiler configuration for CUDA
##########################################

cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
cuda.output = ${OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.o

cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc $$CUDA_DEFINES -m64 -g -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c $$NVCCFLAGS $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS  ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}

cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C 
cuda.depend_command = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc $$CUDA_DEFINES -g -M $$CUDA_INC $$NVCCFLAGS ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
# Tell Qt that we want add more stuff to the Makefile
QMAKE_EXTRA_UNIX_COMPILERS += cuda
```

Comment: This looks like a simple linking order problem. Try specifying your library *before* the dependencies, not after them

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had the same idea and ended up moving it from the front (top) to the back (bottom) of the list to see if the order was causing this (I'm away from dev machine ATM but I'm quite certain I tried this).

Comment: This would probably be easier to diagnose if you can capture the actual link command being generated as well as the full output of the error message you have excerpted.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, added the make command and linking output. Note that the output is after the first failed command and outputs the problems from the linking stage.

Comment: I was able to build by adding the components of myLib.a into the CUDA_SOURCES. While this works it's not an optimal solution with respect to build times and application binary size....

Answer (score 2):

Try these in your .pro file. I used it to link to CUDA on Linux successfully :

```
# Define output directories

CONFIG(release, debug|release): CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = release/cuda
else: CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = debug/cuda


# This makes the .cu files appear in your project
OTHER_FILES +=  vectorAddition.cu

# CUDA settings <-- may change depending on your system
CUDA_SOURCES += vectorAddition.cu


unix{
    CUDA_SDK = "/usr/local/cuda-5.5/"   # Path to cuda SDK install
    CUDA_DIR = "/usr/local/cuda-5.5/"   # Path to cuda toolkit install
}

unix: SYSTEM_NAME = unix

SYSTEM_TYPE = 32            # '32' or '64', depending on your system
CUDA_ARCH = sm_30           # Type of CUDA architecture, for example 'compute_10', 'compute_11', 'sm_10'
NVCC_OPTIONS = --use_fast_math

# include paths
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include
               #$$CUDA_SDK/common/inc/ \
               #$$CUDA_SDK/../shared/inc/

# library directories
unix:{
    QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib
}


# Add the necessary libraries
unix:
{
    CUDA_LIBS = -lcuda -lcudart
    # The following makes sure all path names (which often include spaces) are put between quotation marks
    CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')
    NVCC_LIBS = $$join(CUDA_LIBS,' -l','-l', '')
    LIBS += $$CUDA_LIBS
}

# Configuration of the Cuda compiler
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    # Debug mode
    cuda_d.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda_d.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o

    unix: cuda_d.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc -D_DEBUG $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$NVCC_LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}

    cuda_d.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda_d
}
else {
    # Release mode
    cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o

    unix: cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$NVCC_LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}

    cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nejat. As far as I could tell your configuration does not add any new elements to my initial PRO file except not adding the depend_command, which I also removed from mine (did not notice any difference).